# create array based on one unique value

Tags: php, foreach

I have following array `uidValues`. I want to create final array based on `uid`.
Will concatenate values if uid is same in loop.

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
    [id] => 1 
    [pid] => 121 
    [uid] => 1  
    )
[1] => Array ( 
    [id] => 2 
    [pid] => 13
    [uid] => 1
    )
[2] => Array ( 
    [id] => 5 
    [pid] => 121 
    [uid] => 1
    )
)
```

i want to create final array like..

```
 Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
    [id] => 1,2,5 
    [pid] => 121,13,121 
    [uid] => 1  
    ) 
)
```

how i can make it using `foreach` loop?

I tried following code..

```
foreach($uidValues as $r)
    {

        if(in_array($r['uid'],$finalArray))
        {   

            $finalArray['id'] .= ','.$r['id'];                                                                               
            $finalArray['pid'] .= $r['pid'];          
            $finalArray['uid'] = ','.$r['uid'];         

        }
        else{

            $finalArray[] = array("id" => $r['id'], "pid" => $r['pid'], "uid" => $r['uid']);

        }               

    }
```

Comment: Use the `uid` as key for your new array. BTW have you tried anything?

Comment: @b0s3 yes. updated question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try simply as

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $hash = $value['uid'];
    if (isset($result[$hash])) {
        $result[$hash]['id'] = $result[$hash]['id'] . ',' . $value['id'];
        $result[$hash]['pid'] = $result[$hash]['pid'] . ',' . $value['pid'];
        $result[$hash]['uid'] = $result[$hash]['uid'] . ',' . $value['uid'];
    } else {
        $result[$hash]['id'] = $value['id'];
        $result[$hash]['pid'] = $value['pid'];
        $result[$hash]['uid'] = $value['uid'];
    }
}

print_r(array_values($result));
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://eval.in/420328)

Comment: Depending on the `uid`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$before = array(
    '0' => array(
        'id'  => 1,
        'pid' => 121,
        'uid' => 1,
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'id'  => 2,
        'pid' => 13,
        'uid' => 1,
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'id'  => 5,
        'pid' => 121,
        'uid' => 1,
    ),
);

$after = array();
foreach ($before as $row) {
    if (array_key_exists($row['uid'], $after)) {
        $after[$row['uid']]['id'] .= ',';
        $after[$row['uid']]['pid'] .= ',';
    } else {
        $after[$row['uid']]['uid'] = $row['uid'];
    }

    $after[$row['uid']]['id'] .= $row['id'];
    $after[$row['uid']]['pid'] .= $row['pid'];
}
```

You can then drop array keys to get exact same array:

```
$after = array_values($after);
```

**Output:**

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'uid' => 1,
    'id' => '1,2,5',
    'pid' => '121,13,121',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps me.

Answer (score -1):

As [@b0s3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2500658/b0s3) said in the comments: use `uid` as key for the new array.

```
foreach($uidValues as $item) {

        $result[$item['uid']]['pid'][]  = $item['pid'];
        $result[$item['uid']]['id'][]   = $item['id'];

}
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [pid] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 121
                    [1] => 13
                    [2] => 121
                )

            [id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 5
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: my desire output array is different